# Chrome DnD support?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I'm looking to construct a really cool shopping cart along the lines of [this one](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/implementing-html5-drag-and-drop-new-premium-tutorial/) from netTutsPlus.

Now, I'm going to modify it a little bit, but I also noticed that Chrome doesn't support the DnD feature they implement in that tutorial.

Now, for the sake of simplicity, I would like to keep my solution along the lines of this tutorial, but I *need* Chrome support.  And for the matter, Opera would be nice too.

Would anyone here be able to suggest a solution for Chrome and Opera (if there is just one that works for both of those browsers that would be great), or, if I should build this shopping cart a completely different way.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Just realized, that this actually appears to work on Chrome! :)

Is there a reason it isn't listed as supported on the HTML5doctore website, then?

Hmm, either way, it *supposedly* doesn't work in Opera either...  If it really does work in every version of Chrome, I'll change the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to implement Drag and Drop, the tutorial in HTML5 Rocks is super great!
http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/dnd/basics/

It works on all browsers (IE9, FF, Chrome, Safari) except Opera.